# .NET Framework 4.8 Install Fail Windows Server 2019

Tags: .net, windows, frameworks, .net-4.8, windows-server-2019

I've searched long and hard for a "fix" for this and cannot seem to locate one. Here's the issue.

Have a VM server up on AWS (I contract for a very large federal gov't agency) that is configured with Windows Server 2019. According to the registry, .NET Framework 4.8 is installed.

[image]

Release 528049 indicates .NET Framework 4.8

My solution, created and edited on my local, federal gov't agency supplied laptop, has .NET Framework 4.8 installed and that is the target framework when one looks at the properties of the project on said local laptop.

I've uploaded the entire solution to the server, installed Visual Studio 2019 up there and when I look at the properties of the project there, this is what I see...

[image]

I have attempted to re-install the .NET Framework 4.8 and it consistently fails due to "Cannot find object or property". I've also installed the "Microsoft .NET Framework Repair Tool" and it fails to fix anything. I cannot get the .NET Framework 4.8 to appear in the "Target framework" drop down of the project properties. Anyone know how to fix this???

P.S. I need the .NET Framework 4.8 because interal federal gov't agency vulnerability webscans indicate that ASP.NET applications like the one I am working are required to have it. And Windows Server 2019 does not support 4.8.1.

Answer (score 1):

Please check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/440811/net-framework-4-8-on-windows-server-2019-installat

And proceed to install :

```
https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/7afca223-55d2-470a-8edc-6a1739ae3252/c8c829444416e811be84c5765ede6148/ndp48-devpack-enu.exe
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33869268)